# Skip empty objects when deserializing array with serde

Tags: rust, serde

I need to deserialize an array (JSON) of a type let call `Foo`. I have implemented this and it works well for most stuff, but I have noticed the latest version of the data will sometimes include erroneous empty objects.

Prior to this change, each `Foo` can be de-serialized to the following enum:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Foo<'s> {
    Error {
        // My current workaround is using Option<Cow<'s, str>>
        error: Cow<'s, str>,
    },
    Value {
        a: u32,
        b: i32,
        // etc.
    }
}

/// Foo is part of a larger struct Bar.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub struct Bar<'s> {
    foos: Vec<Foo<'s>>,
    // etc.
}
```

This struct may represent one of the following JSON values:

```
// Valid inputs
[]
[{"a": 34, "b": -23},{"a": 33, "b": -2},{"a": 37, "b": 1}]
[{"error":"Unable to connect to network"}]
[{"a": 34, "b": -23},{"error":"Timeout"},{"a": 37, "b": 1}]

// Possible input for latest versions of data 
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{"a": 34, "b": -23},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{"error":"Timeout"},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

This does not happen very often, but it is enough to cause issues. Normally, the array should include 3 or less entries, but these extraneous empty objects break that convention. There is no meaningful information I can gain from parsing `{}` and in the worst cases there can be hundreds of them in one array.

I do not want to error on parsing `{}` as the array still contains other meaningful values, but I do not want to include `{}` in my parsed data either. Ideally I would also be able to use `tinyvec::ArrayVec<[Foo<'s>; 3]>` instead of a `Vec<Foo<'s>>` to save memory and reduce time spent performing allocation during paring, but am unable to due to this issue.

How can I skip `{}` JSON values when deserializing an array with `serde` in Rust?

I also put together a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=84e67690aad395d9483a7a22a13ec387) with some test cases to try different solutions.

Comment: I don't think you can without a custom `Deserialize` implementation.

Comment: Yea, I suspect I need to use `#[serde(deserialize_with = "foobar")]`, but I don't know how I would write one for this use case that can detect empty objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, but not performant, solution would be to define an enum that captures both the `Foo` case and the empty case, deserialize into a vector of those, and then filter that vector to get just the nonempty ones.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum FooDe<'s> {
    Nonempty(Foo<'s>),
    Empty {},
}

fn main() {
    let json = r#"[
        {},{},{},{},{},{},
        {"a": 34, "b": -23},
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{},
        {"error":"Timeout"},
        {},{},{},{},{},{}
    ]"#;
    let foo_des = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<FooDe>>(json).unwrap();
    let foos = foo_des
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|item| {
            use FooDe::*;
            match item {
                Nonempty(foo) => Some(foo),
                Empty {} => None,
            }
        })
        .collect();
    let bar = Bar { foos };
    println!("{:?}", bar);

    // Bar { foos: [Value { a: 34, b: -23 }, Error { error: "Timeout" }] }
}
```

Conceptually this is simple but you're allocating a lot of space for `Empty` cases that you ultimately don't need. Instead, you can control exactly how deserialization is done by implementing it yourself.

```rust
struct BarVisitor<'s> {
    marker: PhantomData<fn() -> Bar<'s>>,
}

impl<'s> BarVisitor<'s> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        BarVisitor {
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

// This is the trait that informs Serde how to deserialize Bar.
impl<'de, 's: 'de> Deserialize<'de> for Bar<'s> {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        impl<'de, 's: 'de> Visitor<'de> for BarVisitor<'s> {
            // The type that our Visitor is going to produce.
            type Value = Bar<'s>;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("a list of objects")
            }

            fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut access: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error>
            where
                V: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut foos = Vec::new();

                while let Some(foo_de) = access.next_element::<FooDe>()? {
                    if let FooDe::Nonempty(foo) = foo_de {
                        foos.push(foo)
                    }
                }

                let bar = Bar { foos };

                Ok(bar)
            }
        }

        // Instantiate our Visitor and ask the Deserializer to drive
        // it over the input data, resulting in an instance of Bar.
        deserializer.deserialize_seq(BarVisitor::new())
    }
}

fn main() {
let json = r#"[
        {},{},{},{},{},{},
        {"a": 34, "b": -23},
        {},{},{},{},{},{},{},
        {"error":"Timeout"},
        {},{},{},{},{},{}
    ]"#;
    let bar = serde_json::from_str::<Bar>(json).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", bar);

    // Bar { foos: [Value { a: 34, b: -23 }, Error { error: "Timeout" }] }
}
```

Comment: I was able to adapt this to a function I could apply with `#[deserialize_with = "skip_empty"]`. The code for that can be found on this [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3b9ed99515f9f19e024f4bb53e2b4f63). However, I did remove `access.size_hint()` since it seemed likely that it would partially defeat the purpose of the skipping empty objects on some data formats by still allocating space for them.

Comment: You might want to make the checks for `FooDe` tighter, because right now `{"a": "Foo"}` is treated as empty. If only the empty object is allowed, you probably need to change the order and mix in some `deny_unknown_fields`.

Comment: @Locke good catch about `Vec::with_capacity()`. @jonasbb Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[`serde_with::VecSkipError`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/2.0.0/serde_with/struct.VecSkipError.html) provides a way to ignore any elements which fail deserialization, by skipping them. This will ignore any errors and not only the empty object `{}`. So it might be too permissive.

```rust
#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct Bar<'s> {
    #[serde_as(as = "serde_with::VecSkipError<_>")]
    foos: Vec<Foo<'s>>,
}
```

[Playground](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aserde%20%3D%20%7Bversion%20%3D%20%22*%22%2C%20features%20%3D%20%5B%22derive%22%5D%7D%0Aserde_with%20%3D%20%22*%22%0Aserde_json%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Ause%20serde%3A%3ADeserialize%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aborrow%3A%3ACow%3B%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Deserialize%2C%20PartialEq%2C%20Eq%2C%20Debug)%5D%0A%23%5Bserde(untagged)%5D%0Apub%20enum%20Foo%3C%27s%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Error%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20My%20current%20workaround%20is%20using%20Option%3CCow%3C%27s%2C%20str%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3A%20Cow%3C%27s%2C%20str%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20Value%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%3A%20u32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%3A%20i32%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20etc.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bserde_with%3A%3Aserde_as%5D%0A%23%5Bderive(Deserialize)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20Bar%3C%27s%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%5Bserde_as(as%20%3D%20%22serde_with%3A%3AVecSkipError%3C_%3E%22)%5D%0A%20%20%20%20foos%3A%20Vec%3CFoo%3C%27s%3E%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20test_deserialize(json_string%3A%20%26str%2C%20expected%3A%20%26%5BFoo%3C%27_%3E%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20out%20%3D%20match%20serde_json%3A%3Afrom_str%3A%3A%3CBar%3E(json_string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(v)%20%3D%3E%20v%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(e)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Failed%3A%20Deserialize%20resulted%20in%20error%3A%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20e)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20out.foos.len()%20!%3D%20expected.len()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Failed%3A%20Array%20length%20missmatch%3A%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20%26out.foos)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20expected.iter().zip(out.foos.iter()).any(%7C(a%2C%20b)%7C%20a%20!%3D%20b)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Failed%3A%20Parsed%20values%20did%20not%20match%3A%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20%26out.foos)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Passed%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%5D%7D%22%23%2C%20%26%5B%5D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%7B%22a%22%3A%2034%2C%20%22b%22%3A%20-23%7D%2C%7B%22a%22%3A%2033%2C%20%22b%22%3A%20-2%7D%2C%7B%22a%22%3A%2037%2C%20%22b%22%3A%201%7D%5D%7D%22%23%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2034%2C%20b%3A%20-23%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2033%2C%20b%3A%20-2%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2037%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%7B%22error%22%3A%22Unable%20to%20connect%20to%20network%22%7D%5D%7D%22%23%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5BFoo%3A%3AError%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3A%20Cow%3A%3Afrom(%22Unable%20to%20connect%20to%20network%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%7B%22a%22%3A%2034%2C%20%22b%22%3A%20-23%7D%2C%7B%22error%22%3A%22Timeout%22%7D%2C%7B%22a%22%3A%2037%2C%20%22b%22%3A%201%7D%5D%7D%22%23%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2034%2C%20b%3A%20-23%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AError%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3A%20Cow%3A%3Afrom(%22Timeout%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2037%2C%20b%3A%201%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%22a%22%3A%2034%2C%20%22b%22%3A%20-23%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%22error%22%3A%22Timeout%22%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%7D%22%23%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2034%2C%20b%3A%20-23%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AError%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3A%20Cow%3A%3Afrom(%22Timeout%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%5D%7D%22%23%2C%20%26%5B%5D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20test_deserialize(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%23%22%7B%22foos%22%3A%5B%7B%22a%22%3A%2034%2C%20%22b%22%3A%20-23%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C%7B%22error%22%3A%22Timeout%22%7D%5D%7D%22%23%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AValue%20%7B%20a%3A%2034%2C%20b%3A%20-23%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Foo%3A%3AError%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20error%3A%20Cow%3A%3Afrom(%22Timeout%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: This seems like by far the most convenient solution, but I do worry that it would cover up meaningful errors. I can see this being useful in cases where you have control over the data format and want to filter out malformed results, but since I am receiving data from a third-party source it is harder to determine who is at fault for errors during parsing.

Comment: In that case be careful with the solution of BallpointBen. The check for empty objects `{}` is not quite right. For example, `{"a": "Foo"}` will be treated as empty and ignored.

Comment: Good catch. I'll make sure to apply `#[serde(deny_unknown_fields)]` to the relevant structs.